# Strange Nuance of self in Method Argument List

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I've encountered a pythonic curiosity whose meaning eludes me.

I've found that method dispatch using a dictionary in a class appears to work differently, depending on whether the dispatch is done in `__init__()`.  The difference is whether the selected method is invoked with or without the self argument.

Code illustration:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class strange(object):
    def _eek(): # no self argument
        print "Hi!\n"

    dsp_dict = {"Get_eek" : _eek}
    noideek = dsp_dict["Get_eek"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.ideek = self.dsp_dict["Get_eek"]
        self.ideek2 = self._eek
        self.ideek3 = self.noideek

    def call_ideek(self):
        try:
            self.ideek()
        except TypeError:
            print "Alas!\n"

    def call_ideek2(self):
        try:
            self.ideek2()
        except TypeError:
            print "Alas!\n"

    def call_ideek3(self):
        try:
            self.ideek3()
        except TypeError:
            print "Alas!\n"

    def call_noideek(self):
        try:
            self.noideek()
        except TypeError:
            print "Alas!\n"

x=strange()
print "Method routed through __init__() using the dictionary:"
x.call_ideek()
print "Method routed through __init__() directly:"
x.call_ideek2()
print "Method routed through __init__() using attribute set from dictionary:"
x.call_ideek3()
print "Method not routed through __init__():"
x.call_noideek()
```

Running this, I see:

```
I, kazoo > ./curio.py 
Method routed through __init__() using the dictionary:
Hi!

Method routed through __init__() directly:
Alas!

Method routed through __init__() using attribute set from dictionary:
Alas!

Method not routed through __init__():
Alas!
```

The try-except clauses are catching this sort of thing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./curio.py", line 19, in <module>
    x.call_noideek()
TypeError: call_noideek() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

That is, if the indirection is accomplished in `__init__` by reference to the dictionary, the resulting method is not called with the implicit self argument.

But if the indirection is accomplished either in `__init__` by direct reference to `_eek()`, or by creating a new attribute (`noideek`) and setting it from the dictionary, or even in `__init__` by reference to the attribute originally set from the dictionary, then the self argument is in the call list.

I can work with this, but I don't understand it.  Why the difference in call signature?

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at this

```
>>> x.ideek
<function _eek at 0x036AB130>
>>> x.ideek2
<bound method strange._eek of <__main__.strange object at 0x03562C30>>
>>> x.ideek3
<bound method strange._eek of <__main__.strange object at 0x03562C30>>
>>> x.noideek
<bound method strange._eek of <__main__.strange object at 0x03562C30>>
>>> x.dsp_dict
{'Get_eek': <function _eek at 0x036AB130>}
>>> x._eek
<bound method strange._eek of <__main__.strange object at 0x03562C30>>
```

You can see the difference between static methods and class methods here.

When you store the class method in that dict, it loses the information about it's enclosing class and is treated as a function (see output of `x.dsp_dict`).

Only if you assign that function to `noideek` **in the class context**, it will then **become a class method *again***.

Whereas when referencing the dict from the init method, python threats it as a static method ("function") not changing anything and omnitts the self parameter. (`ideek`)

`ideek2` and `ideek3` can be seen as "aliases" where that class method is only re-referenced.

Comment: OK, very good, thanks.  I can see what you mean from this exercise in introspection, and this moves things forward. So, now, what is the part of the Python standard that decrees that class methods lose information about enclosing classes when stored in dictionaries (and, presumably, in lists)?